# How do we get this look? Is it a filter or a camera setting

Tags: effect

[image][image][image]
How does one get this effect in pictures. Is it a filter or photoshop

Comment: What is  “this look“  what are the qualities and attributes of these photos that you want to try to replicate ?

Comment: Please describe, using words, what the effect you want to replicate is. For more, please see: [Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3881/15871) and [What's the best way to ask a “How do I achieve this effect?” question?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/677/15871)

Comment: I want to add that this is a great, on topic question, and providing examples is great. But we need more specifics, because "this look" could mean the general low exposure, the color cast, the blurring, the dark background, or any of a number of things. Some of these things differ significantly in your examples, so I'd be hard-pressed to even describe "a look" for these. If you can describe what you want, we can help you better.

Comment: See [How can I create this 'medieval look' using an entry-level camera like the Nikon D3300?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/97686/75526)

Comment: All of the above.  Color cast, dark background, general low exposure. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**The images were likely edited separately from each other** because white balance, saturation, and contrast varies among them.

- White balance, which varies among the images, can be controlled by adjusting **temperature** and **tint**. The first has a magenta cast. The second has a green cast.
- All images appear to be **underexposed**, which can be adjusted by altering **exposure** or **gamma**.
- Saturation can be controlled by adjusting **saturation**, **levels**, or **curves**. The second image appears to have had the greatest decrease in saturation. The third image the least.
- Contrast can be controlled by adjusting **levels**, **curves**, or **shadows and highlights**.
- Field of view and depth of field are controlled by choosing appropriate focal lengths and apertures. The images appear to have been taken at different focal lengths and apertures. If they were all captured with a single lens, a zoom lens with variable max aperture was most likely used.
- The images have compression artifacts caused by saving with low JPEG quality settings.